# how can i add a table-style caption to a longtable in IEEEtran?

Tags: captions

i have a longtable, but the caption comes does not come out to be upper case like a regular table. also i need the caption under the table number, not in the same line.
here is my code:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[4-9]
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{State Table for My Machine}\label{design1}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\hline
a&b&c&d\\
\hline
1&2&3&4\\
\hline
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
\onecolumn
\begin{longtable}{lccccccccccccccr}
\caption{State Table for My Machine}\label{design2}\\ 
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Initial State} & R & C & sel & loc & \multicolumn{6}{c}{mol} & cre & con & r\_c & Final State \\
                &                 &   &   &     &     & 5  & 4  & 3 & 2 & 1 & 0 &     &     &      &             \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{16}{l}{Table \ref{design} continued from previous page...}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Initial State} & R & C & sel & loc & \multicolumn{6}{c}{mol} & cre & con & r\_c & Final State \\
                &                 &   &   &     &     & 5  & 4  & 3 & 2 & 1 & 0 &     &     &      &             \\
\hline
\endhead
\hline
\endfoot
x               & xxxx            & x & x & x   & xx  & 0  & 0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0   & 0   & 0    & OOO         \\ \hline
OOO             & 0000            & 0 & 0 & x   & x0  & 1  & 1  & 1 & 1 &   &   & 0   & 0   & 0    & PO          \\
                & 0000            & 0 & 0 & x   & x1  &    &    &   &   & 1 & 1 & 0   & 0   & 0    & OOP         \\
                & 0000            & 0 & 1 & x   & 00  & 1  & 0  &   &   &   &   & 0   & 1   & 0    & XOO         \\
                & 0000            & 0 & 1 & x   & 01  &    &    & 1 & 0 &   &   & 0   & 1   & 0    & OXO         \\
                & 0000            & 0 & 1 & x   & 10  &    &    &   &   & 1 & 0 & 0   & 1   & 0    & OOX         \\
                & 0000            & 1 & 0 & x   & 00  & 0  & 1  &   &   &   &   & 0   & 1   & 1    & XOO         \\
                & 0000            & 1 & 0 & x   & 01  &    &    & 0 & 1 &   &   & 0   & 1   & 1    & OXO         \\
                & 0000            & 1 & 0 & x   & 10  &    &    &   &   & 0 & 1 & 0   & 1   & 1    & OOX         \\
                & 0000            & 1 & 1 & 0   & 00  & 0  & 1  &   &   &   &   & 0   & 1   & 1    & XOO         \\
                & 0000            & 1 & 1 & 0   & 01  &    &    & 0 & 1 &   &   & 0   & 1   & 1    & OXO         \\
                & 0000            & 1 & 1 & 0   & 10  &    &    &   &   & 0 & 1 & 0   & 1   & 1    & OOX         \\
                & 0000            & 1 & 1 & 1   & 00  & 1  & 0  &   &   &   &   & 0   & 1   & 0    & XOO         \\
                & 0000            & 1 & 1 & 1   & 01  &    &    & 1 & 0 &   &   & 0   & 1   & 0    & OXO         \\
                & 0000            & 1 & 1 & 1   & 10  &    &    &   &   & 1 & 0 & 0   & 1   & 0    & OOX         \\ 
\end{longtable}
\twocolumn
\lipsum[5]
\end{document}`
```

When i run it, i get two tables. these are the snapshots:
[image]

[image]

i want table 2 to have the same caption format as table 1. please help!

Comment: Longtable modifies \caption so that it can repeat the caption on every page and add "Cont." to the end.  One solution is to use \captionof{table}{...} (capt-of package) before starting longtable.

Comment: I tried this solution too. i works perfectly. however there is a lont of blank space between the caption and the longtable in this solution. the solution in the answer is awesome.

Comment: previously, i have done this: i had a \begin{table}, \caption{}, \label{}, \end{table}. the i put my long-table underneath. this was a similar solution. again there was white space between the caption and the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other solution is to modify `\LT@makecaption` using one of the table formats from IEEEtran.cls (there are a LOT of different versions).

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{capt-of}

\makeatletter
\def\LT@makecaption#1#2#3{%
\LT@mcol\LT@cols c{\hbox to\z@{\hss\parbox[t]\LTcapwidth{%
\footnotesize\bgroup\par\centering\@IEEEtabletopskipstrut{\normalfont\footnotesize #2}\\{\normalfont\footnotesize\scshape #3}\par\addvspace{0.5\baselineskip}\egroup\endgraf%
\@IEEEtablecaptionsepspace}%
\hss}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[4-9]
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{State Table for My Machine\label{design1}}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\hline
a&b&c&d\\
\hline
1&2&3&4\\
\hline
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
\onecolumn
\begin{longtable}{lccccccccccccccr}
\caption{State Table for My Machine}\label{design2}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Initial State} & R & C & sel & loc & \multicolumn{6}{c}{mol} & cre & con & r\_c & Final State \\
                &                 &   &   &     &     & 5  & 4  & 3 & 2 & 1 & 0 &     &     &      &             \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{16}{l}{Table \ref{design} continued from previous page...}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Initial State} & R & C & sel & loc & \multicolumn{6}{c}{mol} & cre & con & r\_c & Final State \\
                &                 &   &   &     &     & 5  & 4  & 3 & 2 & 1 & 0 &     &     &      &             \\
\hline
\endhead
\hline
\endfoot
x               & xxxx            & x & x & x   & xx  & 0  & 0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0   & 0   & 0    & OOO         \\ \hline
OOO             & 0000            & 0 & 0 & x   & x0  & 1  & 1  & 1 & 1 &   &   & 0   & 0   & 0    & PO          \\
                & 0000            & 0 & 0 & x   & x1  &    &    &   &   & 1 & 1 & 0   & 0   & 0    & OOP         \\
                & 0000            & 0 & 1 & x   & 00  & 1  & 0  &   &   &   &   & 0   & 1   & 0    & XOO         \\
                & 0000            & 0 & 1 & x   & 01  &    &    & 1 & 0 &   &   & 0   & 1   & 0    & OXO         \\
                & 0000            & 0 & 1 & x   & 10  &    &    &   &   & 1 & 0 & 0   & 1   & 0    & OOX         \\
                & 0000            & 1 & 0 & x   & 00  & 0  & 1  &   &   &   &   & 0   & 1   & 1    & XOO         \\
                & 0000            & 1 & 0 & x   & 01  &    &    & 0 & 1 &   &   & 0   & 1   & 1    & OXO         \\
                & 0000            & 1 & 0 & x   & 10  &    &    &   &   & 0 & 1 & 0   & 1   & 1    & OOX         \\
                & 0000            & 1 & 1 & 0   & 00  & 0  & 1  &   &   &   &   & 0   & 1   & 1    & XOO         \\
                & 0000            & 1 & 1 & 0   & 01  &    &    & 0 & 1 &   &   & 0   & 1   & 1    & OXO         \\
                & 0000            & 1 & 1 & 0   & 10  &    &    &   &   & 0 & 1 & 0   & 1   & 1    & OOX         \\
                & 0000            & 1 & 1 & 1   & 00  & 1  & 0  &   &   &   &   & 0   & 1   & 0    & XOO         \\
                & 0000            & 1 & 1 & 1   & 01  &    &    & 1 & 0 &   &   & 0   & 1   & 0    & OXO         \\
                & 0000            & 1 & 1 & 1   & 10  &    &    &   &   & 1 & 0 & 0   & 1   & 0    & OOX         \\ 
\end{longtable}
\twocolumn
\lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is so great! i have been stuck at this for a week. thanks a bunch!